# Use things from <input>

Tags: html

I understand the title is vague, this is because I don't know how to say what I am looking for.

I am trying to remember how to write in HTML, CSS, JS. And to start off I wanted to do a fun project to bypass my school's system on blocking Youtube videos. I know this is not productive in any shape or form, but its something to do. I currently have:

I am trying to figure out how to use a input on another html page (my index.html) to open the html file below. But where I have *[THE YOUTUBE VIDEO]* there is the Youtube video they entered on the first page.

I tried to look up how to do this, but my main issue is I don't know what to research.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Video Unblocker</title>

  <style>
    .heybuddy {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding-top: 56.25%;
    }

    .buddy2 {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="heybuddy">

    <iframe class="buddy2" src="[THE YOUTUBE VIDEO]"></iframe>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Look up query strings. You can pass variable values from one page to another.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that!

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=  search string with spaces replaced by +

Comment: Seblor, is there some way I can get around that? I have seen sites like youtube video downloaders that display a preview of the video, and I can watch the entire video with no interruptions.

Comment: `<script>document.write('<iframe class="buddy2" src="'+new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("youtubeURL")+'"></iframe>');</script>`